# Getting specific Season and Episode info from OMDBAPI.com using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, video

Getting a specific Season and Episode back for a Series.

I am getting the data back I want but I think it's in the wrong format.

**Here is my code**

```
$Result = [xml] (Invoke-WebRequest "http://www.omdbapi.com/? 
Season=1&Episode=2&t=Reacher&apikey=$ApiKey")
```

**Here is my result:**

Cannot convert value

```
"{"Title":"First Dance","Year":"2022","Rated":"TV-MA","Released":"04 Feb 2022","Season":"1",
  "Episode":"2","Runtime":"52 min","Genre":"Action, Crime, Drama","Director":"Sam Hill",
  "Writer":"Lee Child, Nick Santora, Scott Sullivan","Actors":"Alan Ritchson, Malcolm Goodwin, 
  Willa Fitzgerald",
  "Plot":"When more victims are discovered, 
          Reacher attempts to get answers but is set up.
          Roscoe discovers a threatening message.","Langu
 age":"English","Country":"N/A","Awards":"N/A",
 Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjYxOWZhZGEtMTRiMy00NWYzLWJmYjYtOTkxZDlkMGZmM2QxXkEyXkFqcG
 deQXVyMTM3MTQxNzk@._V1_SX300.jpg",
 "Ratings":[{"Source":"Internet Movie Database","Value":"8.1/10"}],"Metascore":"N/A", "imdbRating":"8.1","imdbVotes":"3639","imdbID":"tt14503476","seriesID":"tt928 
   8030","Type":"episode",
   "Response":"True"}" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". 

Error: "The specified node cannot 
be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."
At H:\_mydocs\MovieCapture\Untitled19.ps1:5 char:1
+ $Result = [xml] (Invoke-WebRequest "http://www.omdbapi.com/?Season=1& ...
```

- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument
  ```

Comment: The format you are getting is json.  Server may not support xml format.  Power shell you can use ConvertFrom-JSON

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$Result = Invoke-WebRequest "http://www.omdbapi.com/?Season=1&Episode=2&t=Reacher&apikey=$ApiKey" | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 10
```